# Qual é a diferença entre DOM e virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript

Vi um framework que trabalhava com *Virtual DOM* e por esse fato se tornava mais rápido que os demais. (framework : facebook reactjs)

Qual é a vantagem e desvantagem em cada um? Como se trabalha com cada um?

Exemplo em js puro

Answer (score 23):

## Diferença entre DOM e Virtual DOM

**DOM** é a representação dos compomentes na página. Você manipula o DOM a fim de manipular estes componentes (criar, recriar, alterar seu estado).

**Virtual DOM** é um framework para manipulação do DOM.

## Como funciona o Virtual DOM

Virtual DOM oferece três recursos:

- Uma representação do DOM real na linguagem JavaScript. O DOM real é então gerado a partir desta representação.
- Computação das diferenças entre o DOM real e a sua representação.
- Aplicação de *patch* para atualizar o DOM real conforme o novo estado da sua representação.

Deste modo, utilizando Virtual DOM você:

- **1)** Cria uma representação do DOM na linguagem do Virtual DOM;
- **2)** Manda o Virtual DOM gerar o DOM real;
- **3)** Quando houver alteração no model, em vez de atualizar a DOM real você simplesmente manda regerar toda a representação Virtual DOM passando o novo estado do model como parâmetro;
- **4)** Então você usa o mecanismo de comparação para obter as diferenças entre a representação do Virtual DOM e o DOM real;
- **5)** E usa o mecanismo de patch que vai atualizar o DOM real conforme as diferenças observadas.

## Por que Virtual DOM é mais rápido

Não necessariamente é mais rápido. Ele pode ser mais rápido se o teu código para verificar e manipular o DOM não for tão eficiente quanto o código dele.

## Qual a vantagem e desvantagem em cada um

Como DOM e Virtual DOM são duas coisas distintas, não há como compará-los.

O que pode ser comparado é o Virtual DOM com outro mecanismo para manipular o DOM ([JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) puro, [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) ou outros frameworks como [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) e [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)).

Neste caso, sobre a vantagem do Virtual DOM, embora a propaganda do [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) seja de que ele é mais rápido por usar Virtual DOM, a propaganda do próprio Virtual DOM diz que sua principal vantagem é a organização do código, que o deixa mais significativo, e a capacidade que ele te oferece de se focar em outras coisas que não a manipulação do DOM. É claro que ele afirma também que faz tudo isso de maneira muito performática.

Ir além na lista de vantagens e desvantagens me parece entrar no opinativo, e eu nem posso opinar porque nunca usei Virtual DOM.

## Exemplo de utilização do Virtual DOM

Obtido do [repositório do Virtual DOM no GitHub](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom).

```
var h = require('virtual-dom/h');
var diff = require('virtual-dom/diff');
var patch = require('virtual-dom/patch');
var createElement = require('virtual-dom/create-element');

// 1: Cria a função que declara como o DOM deve ser
function render(count)  {
    return h('div', {
        style: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'center',
            lineHeight: (100 + count) + 'px',
            border: '1px solid red',
            width: (100 + count) + 'px',
            height: (100 + count) + 'px'
        }
    }, [String(count)]);
}

// 2: Inicializa o documento
var count = 0;  // Precisamos de algum dado do aplicativo. Aqui nós apenas armazenamos um contador.

var tree = render(count);               // Nós precisamos de uma árvore inicial (representação do DOM)
var rootNode = createElement(tree);     // Cria um nó raiz DOM inicial a partir da representação...
document.body.appendChild(rootNode);    // ... e adiciona o nó raiz no documento

// 3: Dispara a lógica de atualização
setInterval(function () {
      // atualiza o dado do aplicativo  
      count++;
      // passando como parâmetro o dado atualizado, recria uma árvore completa para representar a view
      var newTree = render(count);
      // compara a representação recém criada com o DOM real e obtém as diferenças
      var patches = diff(tree, newTree);
      // aplica as diferenças no DOM real
      rootNode = patch(rootNode, patches);
      tree = newTree;
}, 1000);
```

## Virtual DOM nas palavras dos seus criadores:

Traduzido do [repositório do Virtual DOM no GitHub](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom).

> Manipulação manual do DOM é uma bagunça e manter o controle do estado
>   anterior do DOM é difícil. Uma solução para este problema é escrever
>   seu código como se você estivesse recriando o DOM inteiro toda vez que
>   o estado mudasse. Claro, se você de fato recriasse o DOM inteiro toda
>   vez que o estado da aplicação mudasse, seu aplicativo seria muito
>   lento e os seus campos de entrada perderiam o foco.
>
> Virtual-DOM é uma coleção de módulos designados para prover uma forma
>   declarativa de se representar o DOM. Então em vez de atualizar o DOM
>   quando o estado da sua aplicação muda, você simplesmente cria uma
>   árvore virtual (ou "VTRee"), a qual se parece com o estado que você
>   deseja para o DOM. Virtual-DOM vai então descobrir como fazer o DOM
>   ficar igual a esta árvore virtual (com o mesmo estado dela) de maneira
>   eficiente, sem recriar todos os nós do DOM.
>
> Virtual-DOM permite a você atualizar a view sempre que o estado mude
>   através da recriação completa da VTRee da view e através da eficiente
>   atualização do DOM para que ele se pareça exatamente como você o
>   descreveu. Isto resulta em manter a manipulação manual do DOM e também
>   o rastreamento de estado fora do seu código, promovendo uma lógica de
>   renederização limpa e de fácil manutenção para aplicativos Web.

Outras fontes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965738/what-is-virtual-dom
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109361/why-is-reacts-concept-of-virtual-dom-said-to-be-more-performant-than-dirty-mode
- http://fluentconf.com/fluent2014/public/schedule/detail/32395

Comment: Na verdade, o DOM não é bem isto. O DOM é um modelo do documento, ou seja, como está disposto cada elemento no seu documento, ele não é um mecanismo. E o virtual dom não é bem um **framework para manipular o dom** porque na verdade ele não manipula o DOM, ele utiliza o DOM como base para criar o seu DOM próprio, mais reduzido especificado e organizado, isto no momento de seu carregamento, pois com uma aplicação rodando, ao realizar alterações, ele não acessa o DOM, e sim o seu próprio Virtual DOM que foi criado.

Comment: e sobre: **"aplicação de patch para atualizar o DOM real"**, isto faria com que o Virtual DOM perdesse a sua grande vantagem que seria não precisar ficar acessando o DOM real a cada alteração, por isso ele é rápido. E claro que depende do seu código mas o mais lento que ele poderia ficar seria igual a velocidade do DOM real.

Comment: @PauloRoberto DOM é um mecanismo para manipular os componentes no momento que você manipula o DOM a fim de manipular os componentes em si. Se não é um "mecanismo", é um "meio" ou de repente outra palavra mais apropriada (fique a vontade para editar). O restante da resposta acho não deixa dúvida sobre o que ele é. Quanto às suas demais afirmações, estão todas incorretas. Não tem nenhum sentido manipular o Virtual DOM se isto não causar um resultado no DOM em si. Leia a documentação que linkei.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Traduzi na minha resposta a página linkada. Observe como sua visão está equivocada ou no mínimo incompleta. **Todo o objetivo do Virtual DOM é justamente manipular o DOM**. Nem faria sentido não manipular o DOM. Se o DOM não for manipulado, como será reproduzida na página a mudança de estado da aplicação?

Answer (score 2):

Virtual DOM, nada mais é que um **Mini DOM**, que é uma pequena parte do DOM, que seria a  recriação dos objetos DOM **utilizados** contendo apenas o conteúdo necessário, e deixando de lado todas as partes do DOM que não vão ser utilizadas.

E então temos um objeto menor e desvinculado do DOM, por isso podemos modifica-lo e utiliza-lo muito mais rapidamente, sem necessidade nenhuma de ficar acessando o DOM novamente, apenas em algumas pequenas ocasiões, **mas de forma muito rápida**.

Por isso você pode entender que o Virtual DOM é mais rápido, afinal o que seria melhor, manipular um **pequeno objeto desvinculado** ou manipular um objeto dentro do DOM que é uma imensa arvore de objetos?

**A vantagem dele é** esta performance que é obtida mediante a estes fatos, **sua desvantagem seria** não ser tão completo como o DOM, mas acredito que isto não seria um problema, pois há muita coisa no DOM para que você consiga utiliza-lo por completo.

Mas não só isso, o Virtual DOM também se torna mais fácil de dar manutenção, por ser mais compacto e menos complexo.

Há alguns frameworks e algumas libs que estão utilizando atualmente o virtual-dom, dentre elas cito algumas:

## Libs

1. [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/)
2. [Virtual-DOM](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom)

## Frameworks

1. [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/blog/Blazing-Fast-Html.elm)
2. [Mercury](https://github.com/Raynos/mercury)
3. [Mithril](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/)
4. [Om](https://github.com/swannodette/om)
5. [Ractive](http://www.ractivejs.org/)
6. [Tagtree](https://github.com/google/dart-tagtree)
7. [WebSharper.UI.Next](http://wizardsofsmart.net/news/websharper-ui-improvements/)

## Exemplos:

1. [Why React is Awesome](http://jlongster.com/Removing-User-Interface-Complexity,-or-Why-React-is-Awesome#state-settings)
2. [React + D3](https://egghead.io/)
3. [D3 in a virtual room + domino.js](http://bl.ocks.org/vectorsize/8053096)
4. [AngularJS + React](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2014/04/faster-angularjs-rendering-angularjs-and-reactjs/)
5. [Pedestal + Om](https://github.com/TanYewWei/pedestal-om-todo/)
6. [React + bacon.js](http://joshbassett.info/2014/reactive-uis-with-react-and-bacon/)

## Referência:

#### [What is a virtual dom?](http://jbi.sh/what-is-virtual-dom/)

Answer (score 2):

Código em Virtual Dom:

```
var tree = virtualH('footer', {
    id: 'footer',
    className: 'footer'
}, [
    virtualH('span', {
        id: 'todo-count',
        className: 'todo-count'
    }, [
        virtualH('strong', String(todosLeft)),
        todosLeft === 1 ? ' item' : ' items',
        ' left'
    ]),
    virtualH('ul', {
        id: 'filters',
        className: 'filters'
    }, [
        virtualLink('#/', 'All', route === 'all'),
        virtualLink('#/active', 'Active', route === 'active'),
        virtualLink('#/completed', 'Completed', route === 'completed')
    ]),
    virtualH('button', {
        id: 'clear-completed',
        className: 'clear-completed',
        hidden: todosCompleted === 0
    }, 'Clear completed (' + String(todosCompleted) + ')')
]);
return tree;
```

Código em Dom:

```
var tree = domH('footer', {
    id: 'footer',
    className: 'footer'
}, [
    domH('span', {
        id: 'todo-count',
        className: 'todo-count'
    }, [
        domH('strong', String(todosLeft)),
        todosLeft === 1 ? ' item' : ' items',
        ' left'
    ]),
    domH('ul', {
        id: 'filters',
        className: 'filters'
    }, [
        domLink('#/', 'All', route === 'all'),
        domLink('#/active', 'Active', route === 'active'),
        domLink('#/completed', 'Completed', route === 'completed')
    ]),
    domH('button', {
        id: 'clear-completed',
        className: 'clear-completed',
        hidden: todosCompleted === 0
    }, 'Clear completed (' + String(todosCompleted) + ')')
]);
return tree;
```

**Fonte: [JSPERF](http://jsperf.com/virtual-dom-vs-real-dom)**

No site tem um test case.